# Отслеживание подключений к ServerSocket. Netty

Tags: java, клиент-сервер, netty

Пишу мессенджер c использованием сетевой библиотеки Netty.вопрос в следующем,когда сервер(ServerSocket) получает запрос от клиента,он отправляет ответ обратно, это все скрыто в классах библиотеки и реализовано у меня вот так вот:

```
 */
public class Server {
    EventLoopGroup group = new NioEventLoopGroup();
    ServerBootstrap b = new ServerBootstrap();

    public void run() throws InterruptedException {
    b.group(group)
.channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
.childHandler(new SmartHouseServerInitializer());

    ChannelFuture future= b.bind(9989).sync();
    future.channel().closeFuture().sync();
    group.shutdownGracefully();
}
}
public class SmartHouseServerInitializer extends ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel> {

    @Override
    protected void initChannel(SocketChannel socketChannel) throws Exception {
        ChannelPipeline p = socketChannel.pipeline();
       // p.addLast(new StringDecoder());
        //p.addLast(new StringEncoder());
        p.addLast(new ObjectDecoder(ClassResolvers.weakCachingConcurrentResolver(null)));
        p.addLast(new ObjectEncoder());
        p.addLast( new SmartHouseServerHandler());
    }
}
  public class SmartHouseClientHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<Object> {
    @Override
        protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object o) throws Exception {
        String arr=new (String)o;
        ctx.write(arr);
    }
```

То есть тут мы получаем запрос от клиента  и тут же можем отправить ответ на клиент, но сейчас появилась необходимость не отвечать на запрос клиента, а самому серверу инициировать отправку клиенту с помощью уже известного канала с ним.Вопрос в следующем как отслеживать открываемые каналы, чтобы получить в дальнейшем их список и оперировать с помощью них, отправкой запросов с сервера.

Comment: как я понимаю мне надо узнать ip и порт откуда пришел запрос на сервер, но может быть в Netty уже есть обертка для этих манипуляций.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый ^_^

Answer (score 1):

В `SmartHouseClientHandler` надо переопределить методы по подключению/отключению:

```
@Override
public void channelRegistered(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
    super.channelRegistered(ctx);
    // сохраняем подключение
}

@Override
public void channelUnregistered(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
    super. channelUnregistered(ctx);
    // удаляем подключение
}
```

В `channelRegistered` вы можете сохранить куда-нибудь в свой список подключение. В `channelUnregistered` удалить. 
Теперь вы можете инициировать отправку сообщения от сервера к клиенту через этот канал.